# Using a number within a cell as a reference point

Tags: excel, count, worksheet-function

I have a cell with a value in corresponding to a particular cell I wish to start a formula from and another to end it upon. E5=76 F5=340 meaning I wish to start a formula counting values from cell A76:A340, is there a way to use the values from E5 and F5 to tell Excel to count from that row in column A? My data set is very large 4-10k rows and I have around 30 data sets to analyse.

To give an overview of my work, I have a column with time (over a 24h period), a column with a value1-6 and a column counting if adjacent cells (above and below) have the same value of 1-6. So, I end up with a countif column of lots of 0=(no change) and 1=(change in value). I basically want to count how many 1's I have between 1 and 2 o'clock, 2-3,3-4,4-5 etc. etc., but find it very hard to figure out an easy way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`INDIRECT()` will help you. Do it like in one of the options below, depending on what you want to count:

```
=COUNT(INDIRECT("A"&E5&":A"&F5))
=COUNTA(INDIRECT("A"&E5&":A"&F5))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`INDEX`](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/INDEX-function-b61bc266-fe02-4852-aad9-77bf8ca3c036), e.g. to derive the range `A76:A340` from the cell values use this:

`=INDEX(A:A,E5):INDEX(A:A,F5)`

you can use that within other functions like `SUM`, `AVERAGE`, `COUNTIF` etc.

`INDEX` is arguably preferable to [`INDIRECT`](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/indirect-function-ba22e49d-7d4e-4782-a48b-d4007d89477a) because it isn't a "volatile" function which re-calculates each time the sheet is re-calculated (i.e. when anything changes)